# Issue with Inheritance JPA/Hibernate JOINED

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I want implement this schema:

[image]

What I did is:

For Person class:

```
/////***************Class Person ****///////////////
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="role")
    public class Person {
         
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        private String fName;
        private String lName;
        private String email;
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="profil_id")
        private List<Role> listRole;
     
    //getters & setters
    }
```

For other class i did this (this is an example for Student class however for Teacher and Director classes it's the same) :

```
/////***************Class Student ****///////////////
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("etudiant")
public class Etudiant {
     
    // other attributes owned to class
 
//getters & setters
}
```

And this is class Role :

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idRole;
    private String roleName;
     //getters & setters
}
```

The system imposes that the administrator can create persons without any role and in the future this administrator can affect them roles.

Below a code to create, for the first time, a person with role Student (for example) (no problems here):

```
Student s=new Student("me", "mmm", "me@gmail.com");
m.addPerson(s);// "m" it's a defined variable (used in JUnit test)
```

The results for this code is adding student in person table and add his id in student table.

My questions are:

**1. How can i add role to person  ?**
 **2. How can i change role (teacher ==>Director or  Director ==>Teacher ) after adding roles ?**

Answer (score 0):

With JOINED inheritance it's not easy to change the sub-class type while preserving the base-class entry, so instead of inheritance, you can simply use composition.

The Person can have a `@OneToOne(mappedBy)` association to Etudiant, where Etudiant has a `@OneToOne` association back to Person (FK back to Person's PK).

The `Etudiant` can still use inheritance, so it can be `Student`, `PhdStudent`, `Teacher`, `Director`.

This way you can easily turn one `Person` from `Teacher` to `Director`. You just have to change the `person.etudiant` association.